# Error importing Box2d on NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, box2d

I'm trying to make a game in which I need physics and I want to run the logic on the server, but I'm having this problem importing the box2d library into my server, written in NodeJs.

Actually I have the library in a file named "box2d.js"

and it's a module which exports this way

```
    module.exports = Box2D;
```

And in the server I have tried to require the file and the module, none of them worker

```
var Box2D = require('./box2d.js');
var Box2D = require('./Box2D');
```

None of the two options worked, when I run the server It fails and this is the error I get.

> E:\project>node index.js
>
> console.js:39
>
> this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
>       at Console.log (console.js:39:15)
>       at Server. (E:\Sliball\index.js:327:11)
>       at Server.g (events.js:273:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:179:7)
>       at emitListeningNT (net.js:1260:10)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
>       at startup (node.js:146:18)

Any idea about how to fix it? I have already tried 5-6 projects on github, none of them worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict between Box2D.js and the console. I found a half solution here, comment out lines 26 -> 36 of Box2D.js:

[Node.js Box2dWeb error caused by require()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676088/node-js-box2dweb-error-caused-by-require)

But commenting out the offending code seems like a bad idea. Im playing around with it now and Ill let you know if there are any nasty side effects.